# Should jiffies 'catch-up' after suspend/resume cycle?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

After a suspend to RAM followed by resume should we update jiffies to account for the time spent suspended by checking against our always on clock? The clock that jiffies is based on is powered down during suspend/resume so it doesn't continue to increment on its own.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know no, you shouldn't, because jiffies is only the number on times the interrupt of the system timer expires.

Che for example line 54 of [this](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/power/charger-manager.h;h=0e86840eb603186728d6af5d14a3c277f3f4382b;hb=HEAD), this assumes that jiffies stops.

Comment: But this clearly isn't the case for the tick-less (NO_HZ) kernel.